# numpy diff on a pandas Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to use numpy.diff on a pandas Series. Am I right that this is a bug? Or am I doing it wrong?

```
In [163]: s = Series(np.arange(10))

In [164]: np.diff(s)
Out[164]: 
0   NaN
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9   NaN

In [165]: np.diff(np.arange(10))
Out[165]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I am using pandas 0.9.1rc1, numpy 1.6.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pandas implements `diff` like so:

```
In [3]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(10))

In [4]: s.diff()
Out[4]:
0   NaN
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
```

Using `np.diff` directly:

```
In [7]: np.diff(s.values)
Out[7]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [8]: np.diff(np.array(s))
Out[8]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

So why doesn't `np.diff(s)` work? Because np is taking `np.asanyarray()` of the series before finding the `diff`. Like so:

```
In [25]: a = np.asanyarray(s)

In [26]: a 
Out[26]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9

In [27]: np.diff(a)
Out[27]:
0   NaN
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9   NaN
```